# Android Webview Zoom when setUseWideViewPort set to true

Tags: android-webview

I have a webview in a linear layout, which loads images from url on button click, and I wanted them to fit the screen exactly in the beginning, so I used

webview.getSettings().setLoadOverViewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

before adding these, the zoom control buttons were working as I wanted them to, but after adding these, zoom doesnt seem to work, either it force closes or just closes the webview itself.

I am a newbie to android programming, and i tried searching with similar question, couldnt find anything, so any advise would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

Comment: hey thanks for replying, i did use them, they were working fine before i added setLoadOverViewMode and setUseWideViewPort.. after i added these, whenever I try to zoom it either force closes or closes the webview, sorry if i wasnt clear in the question

Answer (score 0):

setLoadOverViewMode means it will load the webview completely zoomed out.
I guess that is the reason zoom controls dont work